# Python ftplib pwd() returns an empty string

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm writing a Python program centered around transferring files from a PC to a target device.
So far I've used the ftplib package for all the other functions in the program.
I've encountered a problem that didn't happen in any of the other devices so far, that the `ftp.pwd()` returns just an empty string, but when I use the `ftp.voidcmd("PWD")` - which is the same as `ftp.pwd()` I get my working directory.

Here is the snippet that relates to the problem, note the I have done the same with a few other devices and it never happened:

```
# CONNECT TO TARGET
ftp = FTP (host)
ftp.login(username , password)

ftp.cwd("/DirName")
# DOESNT WORK
res = ftp.pwd()
print(res)
# WORKS
res = ftp.voidcmd("PWD")
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ftplib is strict about the response code returned by the `PWD` command. Only if the code is `257` as mandated by [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959), the ftplib will consider the response valid and will return the path.

Some obscure FTP servers do not use the `257` code, but some other `2xx` code. Many FTP clients are tolerant and will handle such response as valid. The ftplib is not. You will have to keep using your workaround with `FTP.voidcmd("PWD")`.